# Rails 4 caching causing incorrect id in links

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have added a bunch of cache calls around my site and the result has been horrendous.  For example:

```
 User.all.each do |user|
    cache user do
        link_to user.name, user
    end
 end
```

The links are going to the wrong users page.

Or...

```
 User.all.each do |user|
    cache user do
        <li><%= user.name %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Add Widget', new_user_widget_path(user) %></li>
    end
 end
```

In the above example I'd have a hidden field for the user_id.  But, because of caching the user_id is not the intended user.  So, the widget gets created for the wrong user!

Is this a TurboLink problem?  Caching seems so easy to implement in rails, but...I must be doing something wrong.  I've read the docs on this matter.

Why would caching in an iteration cause links to use the wrong id?

Comment: Does it work without the cache block?

Comment: It does...everything goes back to normal and works fine if I remove the cache block.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over User.all using the each function you call the cache method multiple times saying it should save the cache fragment as "user".

Try to invoke the each loop in the cache block:

```
cache 'user-widgets' do
   User.all.each do |user|
       link_to user.name, user
   end
end
```